# Where can I store my bag in Boston for an hour or two?

Tags: luggage-storage, boston

I'm running the Boston marathon on Patriot's day (2015).

I plan to attend the free dinner buffet for marathon runners on the evening of April 19th. However, they've stated that no backpacks/bags are allowed into the dining area. Since I'm checking into my hotel (in Newton) after the dinner, I will need to store it for an hour or two. I am only carrying a small bag.

Comment: Can you stop by the hotel earlier in the day?

Comment: That is a possibility. But Newton is not exactly that close to the city.

Comment: It ain't exactly that far...

Comment: Where is your bag going to be while you run the marathon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Less than a mile away is [Package Express](http://www.boston-tourism-made-easy.com/boston-storage-lockers.html). Open till 10pm and $5 (according to the link) you should have time to collect again before they close at 10pm, since your function is scheduled to end at 8pm. However in view of the exceptional circumstances I suggest you give them a call first.

If not, and not arriving by train so unable to use Amtrak’s Baggage Room, maybe drop your bag off at your hotel before checking-in. That may waste about an hour but alternatives may add delay anyway.

Another possibility is to ask the dinner’s organisers – not allowed into the dining area does not preclude some cloak-room facilities before that area.

Answer (score 4):

There are a huge number of upscale hotels in the area with valet/luggage/concierge service. While I have never tried in Boston, I have never had problems asking a hotel that I am not staying in to hold a bag for a few hours. In the few cases they have asked for a room number, I tell them I am not staying in the hotel as I give them a $5-10 tip.

Comment: @pnuts yes (e.g., Daytona 500 and NEw Orleans Jazz Fest). On busy days hotels off just rope off a bit of the lobby for extra storage space. The marathon might be different due to heighten security concerns, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which neighborhood in Boston you want to store your bags but there is a service with 5 locations where you can store your bags. The name of the service is called Knock Knock City. [Here is the map](http://knockknock.city/search/boston/luggage-storage/?ref=forum) with all their locations. Only thing is you have to book online to get exact address of the location. You can find them near Museum of Science, Boston Common, North End, Back Bay Station, Boston University and Harvard. Hope this helps.