# How can I find places where I can store my bag in a city?

Tags: luggage, cities

This is a problem I keep having both in the everyday life and sometimes during travelling: I'm going sightseeing and I plan to attend some kind of event where having a backpack would not be welcome, as [in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45911/9356), but let's broaden it to all cities.

Let's say that my hotel reservation is done, where else should I be looking for a spot where I wouldn't spend fortune just for storing my bag? So far I learned that - at least in Poland - train stations often have baggage lockers that can be rented at a reasonable price.

Comment: It will vary from country to country and city to city.  In most of the civilized world hotel where you stayed will store your bag until the end of the day.

Comment: I would expect some patterns to repeat in various cities. Hotel storing my bag is an option if I don't expect to move to a different city where my airport is in, for example.

Comment: Then you should narrow the question.  The situation will vary greatly.

Comment: Train stations are your best option, I guess.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter And if they don't exist?

Comment: In the UK you will find very few left luggage places in train stations, basically the main London stations and almost no others. Some coach stations have left luggage, otherwise you will have to ask wherever you go, or make sure you can take it with you.

Comment: Hotels will keep your bags after you check out, or before you check in. That is your best bet.